# CONVERT_TZ() cannot accept variable as input

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to convert a given date time into another timezone. The code I use is:

```
SELECT `time` INTO @t1 FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(@t1,'+03.00','+00.00') INTO @time1;
SELECT @time1;
```

The problem is that I get a *NULL* result.

I tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2020-10-18 11:27:23','+03.00','+00.00') INTO @time1;
SELECT @time1;
```

and it works without any problem.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in timezone offsets. it should contain `:` (colons sign) instead `.` (dot):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2020-10-18 11:27:23','+03:00','+00:00');
```

Here example: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0a7e569e6fd87bf3999e60f02819e93a&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)